# language link to pick correct language file

Tags: php, require

I have a two language setup, structured like this:

```
includes/languages/lang-it [has the defines]
includes/languages/lang-en [has the defines]
includes/languages/languages [has the languages array]
en/files
en/subs/files
it/files
it/subs/files
```

I have en/sub-1/index.php and en/sub-1/file-1.php and need to be able to change language when in file-1.php page

This is the code I have, and of course it does'nt work

```
require("../../includes/languages/lang-en.php");
<a href="<?php echo '../../' . LANG_ENG . '/sub-1/' . LINK_1 ?>">link to file-1 English</a>
<a href="<?php echo '../../' . LANG_ITA . '/sub-1/' . LINK_1 ?>">link to file-1 Italian</a>
```

Where LANG_ENG and LANG_IT are the directories (en and it)
So I need it to pick the includes/languages/lang-en.php for the the English, and includes/languages/lang-it.php for the Italian.

I guess I need to "**require**" the correct language file before "**LINK-1**", but don't know how.

Comment: The whole point of using language files is that you don't need different directories with code for the different languages. What's the difference between the files in `en/files` and `it/files`?

Comment: You question is Not so clear...... Can you explain the file that is currently being viewed and its directory structure......

Comment: but you only wanna switch the current language, you don't wanna show the definition, right?

Comment: @jeroen the difference is the content, and from my understanding having two distinct directories was good for SEO.

Comment: @kingmaker sorry, let me try explaining better (hopefully), each sub has its index file, and other files when viewing any given file user should be able to switch language by clicking the language link, and same corresponding file should be displayed: I am viewing en/sub-1/file-1 and when clicking on the Italian language the it/sub-1/file-1 should be displayed. Each file has the require("../../includes/languages/lang-xx.php"); code.

Comment: @Jeff Yes only switch language displaying same file, not the definitions.

Comment: @jeroen Clarifying: the files are the same only calling the different language (require("../../includes/languages/lang-xx.php");)
That's the solution I could implement with my limited knowledge, so couldn't do a single directory/file and change language "on the fly", and having the language dir in the url.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

Added $thispage, added variables for the file-name, and put that in the link.
Perhaps there are better ways, but that's what I could think of, and is working.

```
<?php require("../../includes/languages/lang-en.php");?>
<?php // variables for pages to use for language links
$file_1_en="file-1-en.php";
$file_1_it="file-1-it.php";
?>
<?php if ($thisPage=="page name")
echo'
<a href="../../' . LANG_ENG . '/sub-1/' . $file_1_en . '"></a>
<a href="../../' . LANG_ITA . '/sub-1/' . $file_1_it . '"></a>
'?>
```